# Adding Values to JSON Data Set

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, firebase

Let's say I have a JSON data set in the form:

```
{ "fruits": {
    "apple": {
        "color": red,
        "size": small
    }
    "orange": {
        "color": orange,
        "size": small
    }
}
```

How would I add an extra name data point (using something like JavaScript to parse the data) to each one so that they look like this:

```
{ "fruits": {
    "apple": {
        "color": red,
        "size": small,
        "name": apple
    }
    "orange": {
        "color": orange,
        "size": small,
        "name": orange
    }
}
```

I know it might seem redundant to have both an id and name value be the name of the fruit but I need this structure for the program I'm working on. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things first, your properties should be in quotations (unless they are variables, but I don't think that they are, ie:

```
"apple": {
    "color": "red",
    "size": "small"
}
```

And you need a comma between your two fruits.

Now all you have to do is cycle through each fruit and add a new property equal to its name:

```
for (var property in data.fruits) {
    if (data.fruits.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        data.fruits[property].name = property;
    }
}
```

Square bracket notation allows you to access a dynamic or variable property name, which makes setting the name property fairly straight forward. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties) for how to iterate through an array.

The snippet below demonstrates the code in action:

```js
var data = { 
 "fruits": {
  "apple": {
   "color": "red",
   "size": "small"
     },
  "orange": {
   "color": "orange",
   "size": "small"
  }
 }
}



for (var property in data.fruits) {
    if (data.fruits.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
  data.fruits[property].name = property;
    }
}


console.log(data);
```